How to add pvalues for multiple comparisons between more than two groups for categorical variables in gt-summary
I want to compare baseline characteristics between more than two studygroups and I prefer to use gt-summary to make the table.How can I add pvalues, corrected for multiple testing, to the table for comparisons between groups?
I tried the approach as mentioned here:
Gtsummary columns for all post hoc pairwise comparisons
The approach for continuous variables works fine but for categorical values all the mentioned appoaches do not work.
add_stat_pairwise_chisq <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
    # Calculate pairwise p-values
    pw <- chisq.multcomp(to_test = data[[variable]], factor = data[[by]], p.method = "none")
    # convert p-values to list
    index <- 0L
    p.value.list <- list()
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
        for(j in seq_len(nrow(pw$p.value))) {
            index <- index + 1L
            p.value.list[[index]] <- c(pw$p.value[i, j]) %>%
            setNames(glue::glue("**{colnames(pw$p.value)[j]} vs. {rownames(pw$p.value)[i]}**"))
        }
    }

    # convert list to data frame
    p.value.list %>%
    unlist() %>%
    purrr::discard(is.na) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    # formatting/rounding p-values
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(everything(), style_pvalue))
}

table1 <- df %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by= Studiegroep,
    digits = list(age_yrs ~ 0),
    missing="no",
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p})")) %>%
  add_stat(list(all_continuous() ~ add_stat_pairwise, all_categorical() ~ add_stat_pairwise_chisq))



for every categorical variable R gives this error:

There was an error for variable 'Sex':
Error in `[.default`(x, I): invalid subscript type 'closure'

